# Why can you not use ? (question mark) directly on collect() in Rust?

Tags: error-handling, rust, iterator

Let's say we have a buffered reader and want to collect the lines from it and propagate any errors using `?`:

```
let lines: Vec<_> = rdr.lines().collect()?;
```

This does not compile because `` error[E0277]: the size for values of type `str` cannot be known at compilation time ``

Searching around the answer is per https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/49391

```
let lines: Vec<_> = rdr.lines().collect::<Result<Vec<_>,_>>()?;
```

My question is way this is needed, and what exactly this `::<Result<Vec<_>,_>>` means and is doing.

Keep in mind I just started learning Rust.

Comment: personally I write `let lines: Vec<_> = rdr.lines().collect::<Result<_, _>()?;`

Comment: It might make sense to report this as a confusing compiler diagnostic. I would expect the compiler to say something along the lines of "cannot infer return type of `collect()`, type annotations needed".

Comment: @user4815162342 Added this case to the linked Github issue.

Comment: Thanks. Do note, however, that the issue linked in the question is three years old, closed, and complains of a diagnostic that is significantly _better_ than the one you got. Consider just reporting a new issue, so that your case can be examined separately.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are a few pieces that come together to mean that the compiler needs a little help:

### `collect` has a generic type

We can see from [the documentation of `Iterator::try`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.collect) that it takes a generic type called `B`, that that's the type that it returns. It's a bit unusual for a function to *return* a generic type (more commonly, they accept parameters which have generic types), but returning a generic type can make for some really interesting, versatile APIs, and `collect` is definitely one of them! [The documentation of the `collect` method](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.collect) talks about this a bit.

Simplifying your code a little, this means that the compiler can't just look at the code:

```rust
let lines = rdr.lines().collect();
```

and know what type `lines` should have. It could be able to infer this (for instance, if you returned `lines` from the function it could tell that the return type of `collect` should be exactly the same as the return type of the function, or used it as an argument to another one it could unify those types), but on its own this isn't quite enough context.

So - what context could the compiler use to work out the type it should be collecting to... Well, the fact that you have a `?` gives it a hint, but:

### `?` isn't just for `Result`s

`?` can be used for any type which implements the (currently unstable, and probably about to change) [`Try`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Try.html) trait. This means that the compiler can't use the question-mark to infer that the type you're collecting to is a `Result` - maybe you're collecting to an `Option`, or some other type that implements `Try`.

### ? also calls `into`!

Worse than that, `?` doesn't actually just return the error branch of a `Result`, it will try to perform a conversion if it needs to (so e.g. if you have a function which results `Result<(), Box<String>>` you can write `Err(String::from("foo"))?` and Rust will turn this into something like:

```rust
if let Err(err) = Err(String::from("foo")) {
    return err.into();
}
```

Because the `Into` trait is implemented for these types, a `String` can be converted to a `Box<String>` with `Into`, so the `?` operator can save you needing to do the conversion yourself.

However, this adds a whole level of indirection, where the compiler can't always make some "obvious" inferences because it's possible that the error type `collect()` returns isn't the same as the return type of the function, but can just be converted to it!

### Type ascription

One place that you can put this information is you can ascribe the type of a variable. So you could write this code:

```rust
let lines: Result<Vec<_>, _> = rdr.lines().collect();
let lines = lines?;
```

(Each of those `_`s is a place where you're asking the compiler to work out what the type that should be there is from the information it has available to it. In fact, `let lines = rdr.lines().collect();` is the same as `let lines: _ = rdr.lines().collect();` - if the compiler can work it out, it will, but if it can't, it will give an error saying you need to give it more information).

In this code snippet we're saying "The return type of `collect()` needs to be a `Result` where the `Ok` type is a `Vec` of something (compiler, you work it out), and the `Error` type is, well, compiler please work that out too!

That gives quite a lot of information to the compiler, and in a lot of cases that's sufficient, though there may be times where we need to fill in more of those `_`s ourselves.

### Type ascription requires a variable - enter the turbofish

But the code I wrote above is a bit more verbose than the code you wrote. We have two statements rather than one, we make two variables rather than one. And a lot of the point of the `?` operator is to allow us to write concise code!

The syntax you found, colloquially known as the turbofish (because `::<_>` looks kind of funny), is a way to be explicit about what the generic type that the `collect` function takes is:

```rust
collect::<Result<Vec<_>,_>>()
```

This is saying: call the function `collect`, and its generic type should be `Result<Vec<_>, _>`. Just like when we ascribed the type of a variable, this is a way to give the compiler information about what the generic type of the function should be.

So putting that all together, we can write:

```rust
let lines = rdr.lines().collect::<Result<Vec<_>,_>>()?;
```

Which is to say to the compiler: I want you to call `collect` - the generic type I want collect to return is a `Result` of a `Vec` of something (the compiler can work out the rest), and then it knows what you're looking to collect to.